# Why does not "1e-i" work in list comprehensions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

Why is the minus sign below considered an invalid token? There must be something I do not understand here.

```
>>> [1e-i for i in range(-10,10)]
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Normally these things evaluate like a mother:

```
>>> 1e-10
1e-10
```

I'm just curious; I solved my problem with

```
>>> [10**i for i in range(-10,10)]
[1e-10, 1e-09, 1e-08, 1e-07, 1e-06, 1e-05, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`1e-01` etc are numeric literals.  They're seen and tokenized before the script ever runs.  And the rules for such a number almost certainly say "an optional ('E' or 'e', followed by an optional '+' or '-', followed by digits)".  There's no provision for variables in that definition, and changing the definition would make it so numeric literals couldn't be parsed til runtime, which would get very hairy.

Answer (score 2):

Check Python docs for [floating-point literals](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#floating-point-literals):

```
floatnumber   ::=  pointfloat | exponentfloat
...
exponentfloat ::=  (intpart | pointfloat) exponent
...
exponent      ::=  ("e" | "E") ["+" | "-"] digit+
```

The trick is that **numeric literals do not include a sign**; a phrase like -1 is actually an expression composed of the unary operator - and the literal 1.
So, `i` here is considered as a variable in `x - i` expression, even though `x` is a number with an exponent. And it leaves `x` without the exponent part: `1e`. Which is an invalid Python token.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a variable in a `float` literal. `1e-3` is fine, `1e-i` can't be evaluated until runtime and is therefore an invalid literal. It's like expecting `x.14` to evaluate to `3.14` when `x` is `3`. Has nothing to do with list comprehensions.

The solution is as you have found.

Answer (score 1):

`1e-i` is not valid Python syntax. The exponential form is a literal and, as such, is not designed to be dynamic. The lexer says it all: `invalid token`, as in, it has no idea what `1e-i` means.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, `1e-i` is not valid.

You could fix this by doing `float("1e-%d" %i)`:

```
In [114]: [float("1e%d" %i) for i in range(-10,10)]
Out[114]: 
[1e-10,
 1e-09,
 1e-08,
 1e-07,
 1e-06,
 1e-05,
 0.0001,
 0.001,
 0.01,
 0.1,
 1.0,
 10.0,
 100.0,
 1000.0,
 10000.0,
 100000.0,
 1000000.0,
 10000000.0,
 100000000.0,
 1000000000.0]
```

Comment: No offense, but creating a float from a string created from an integer is just stupid.

Comment: I don't disagree, but I couldn't think of a better hack at the time